# ASP.NET web app on EC2 micro instance (613 MB)

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am evaluating hosting a small ASP.NET MVC web app and a SQL Server 2008 Express database on an Amazon EC2 micro instance (613MB RAM). Is 613MB RAM good enough? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on how much traffic you are looking to see, how big your database is, and how well your code is written. The fact is, if you have 10 users and good code, it'll work great, but if you have 1000 users and bad code that doesn't manage resources well, you will run into issues.